# polymer: style paper-input focused floating label when paper-input is inside another element

Tags: css, polymer

I have used a paper-input inside of another element like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <paper-input floatinglabel></paper-input>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

I include this element in my main page thus:

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <my-element></my-element>
</template>
```

I want to style the floating label text when the paper-input element has the focus. What selector do I use to style the floating label text?

I can style the unfocused floating label with:

```
my-element /deep/ .floated-label .label-text {color: red;}
```

But I cannot figure out the selector to set the color when paper-input has the focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Polymer 0.5.1 (the current version), you should be able to style the focused label using the selector `my-element::shadow paper-input[focused] /deep/ .floating-label .label-text`.

Comment: I am using 0.5.1. While your answer didn't work it did send me down the right path. Thank you. I found that `my-element /deep/  paper-input-decorator[focused] /deep/ .floated-label .label-text` did the trick. My paper-input is enclosed in other divs so is not the immediate child of my-element (my fault for not clarifying). Also the parent of the labels is paper-input-decorator. Lastly it is .floated-label (not floating-label). Never knew you could iterate on /deep/.

Comment: Nice to see you got it to work! `/deep/` is a mighty and surely expensive operator, I intuitively try to avoid it wherever possible. But `::shadow paper-input` indeed only would have worked if the input was an immediate child of your template. I got the `paper-input[focused]` from https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/demo.html - if you look at the last two examples in the source, focused seems to work for both the `paper-input-decorator` and the `paper-input` element.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @idleherb who sent me down the right path I found that the following worked:

```
my-element /deep/ paper-input-decorator[focused] /deep/ .floated-label .label-text
```